# Check Multiple Expressions in preg_match function

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a script in which it checks if the input link is http:// or not (if empty). The code is as follows:

```
if(!preg_match('~http://[a-zA-Z0-9]~',$link))
```

The above code only checks for http:// links.

I wanna check multiple expression other than that, like https://, ftp:// etc.

Using && and |, are not giving proper output.

Please help me write a proper code that can match multiple expressions using the OR (|) operators.

Thanks.

Comment: @chris85 Hi.can you show me with complete line of code? I want to check for http://, https://, ftp:// and ftps://.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need multiple `&&` or `||`s in PHP you can check all those protocols with one regex. Group the `f` and `ht` in an optional non-capturing group, then make the `s` optional.

```
if(!preg_match('~(?:f|ht)tps?://[a-zA-Z0-9]~',$link))
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/67qiGQ/1

An alternative approach might be http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php, then checking the `PHP_URL_SCHEME`.